# Cannot import fonts & colors in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I have two installs of Visual Studio 2013 RTM, both from the same ISO, both running on Windows 8.1 machines. Both are set up identically as far as I can tell- same extensions and all. One will allow me to import fonts & colors along with any other settings I choose without issue. The other will allow me to import any settings of my choosing as ***except*** fonts & colors. I either receive no error and nothing changes, or I receive a message that import of fonts & colors failed because of an "internal error" I have tried everything that I can think of:

- I am running VS as administrator
- I have used the "Reset all Settings" option
- I have deleted all of the settings files
- I have reinstalled Visual Studio
- I have tried importing all settings and just fonts and colors off of both an RC and an RTM install.

Nothing works and I am at a loss as to how to solve this.

Comment: Can you show us the 'internal error'?

Comment: There's not much more to it. After import process VS was reporting that it failed to import fonts & colors due to an internal error. No further detail provided of any sort. I seem to have it solved but trying to pin down which change fixed it before posting an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same issue and it looks like its an ID mismatch in the themes.  If you open your exported settings look for the following node in the XML:

```
<Theme Id="{GUID_GOES_HERE}"/>
```

Export your current settings, find the Theme ID of the exported settings, and replace the ID of your desired settings with the one from the freshly exported one and everything should work.

**EDIT:** Issue filed with Microsoft Connect is [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807817/cannot-import-fonts-colors-into-visual-studio-2013). Although they said they'd update the error message to be more informative, it doesn't look like they have.

Comment: I'd forgotten that I had asked this here. I'd posted a question on Microsoft Connect as well before I figured out the theme problem, I just never came back to update. No good reason to duplicate the answer, so I'll just mark this one as the answer and add my findings

Comment: I didn't get any error messages when my imports failed, but this answer fixed my problem too.